# How to put function to this block of PHP code?

Tags: php, html, css, web, mamp

i'm just beginner and i want to call function which will be create the "sub buttons" when button is clicked, how i can do it from this block in echo? help pls

```
<?php function btncreate($filename) {
    echo "<button class='m-1 btn btn-outline-success'>$filename</button>";
}
?>
```

P.S. i need to do it at the same page with the general buttons

i was trynna to do it by using onclick, putting the JS code inside the echo

Comment: If you are doing something when a button on the browser page is clicked, you do it in either javascript, or you AJAX a request to the server for it to present you with something you can add to to the page, again using javascript

Comment: Or you make the button part of a form which can post back a request to the server, if you are happy for it to refresh the page.

Comment: you _can_ use `onlick` to trigger a JS function, but it's usually considered a bit obsolete. Learn about unobtrusive event handlers, e.g. `element.addEventListener("click"...` etc - you can find lots of examples online already, e.g. in MDN and many many tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

First thing first, why do you need to create UI using backend language like that's mostly a Front end language job, Secondly even if you want to do it like this then I say you should use AJAX but that still requires you the combination of Front END with Backend, and if you are looking for a simple button creation upon an event and then save/retrieve something for that button in the backend then I think we can start with JavaScript to create the button on an event (i.e. CLICK) and upon its creation just run an ajax request to save/retrieve whatever you want from that.